# Not able to install python-docx on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, docx, python-docx

I tried to install the `python-docx` on Mac, but seeing the error at `lxml`
Got the `error : Failed building wheel for lxml`

The full error log is as below. JFI, python version : 3.9.6

```
prajwal@Prajwals-Air work_project % pip install python-docx       
Collecting python-docx
  Using cached python_docx-0.8.11-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2
  Using cached lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/prajwalhiremath/Desktop/python_project/work_project/work/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/pip-install-a6tnxrsf/lxml_9fb8fd14a69a4a82abffb9c4cf04df4b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/pip-install-a6tnxrsf/lxml_9fb8fd14a69a4a82abffb9c4cf04df4b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-9e7xc7eb
       cwd: /private/var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/pip-install-a6tnxrsf/lxml_9fb8fd14a69a4a82abffb9c4cf04df4b/
  Complete output (121 lines):
  Building lxml version 4.9.3.
  /private/var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/pip-install-a6tnxrsf/lxml_9fb8fd14a69a4a82abffb9c4cf04df4b/setup.py:67: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
    import pkg_resources
  Building without Cython.
  Building against libxml2 2.9.13 and libxslt 1.1.35
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/objectify.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/etree.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/public-api.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xmlid.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cleanup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xslt.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/debug.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/serializer.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/classlookup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/saxparser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/objectpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/relaxng.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xinclude.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/iterparse.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/parser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/dtd.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/readonlytree.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/extensions.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/schematron.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/docloader.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/nsclasses.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/xsltext.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/proxy.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lxml
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/prajwalhiremath/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/prajwalhiremath/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/prajwalhiremath/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Users/prajwalhiremath/Desktop/python_project/work_project/work/include -I/Users/prajwalhiremath/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  creating var
  creating var/folders
  creating var/folders/pw
  creating var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn
  creating var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T
  cc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitsxkbaobp.c -o var/folders/pw/lrhpmqcj11x4grfg_ggx3t3w0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitsxkbaobp.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
```

I gone through the stack overflow similar issues and tried the possible working tips, but in my case it didn't worked!

such as -> upgrading the setuptools, installing wheel (before installing the python-docx),using `sudo pip install` (it worked for some of them).

Can you please help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Issue is resolved by installing the xcode command line tools `xcode-select --install
`.
Then the `pip install python-docx` is successfully installed.
Thanks.